# Is it enough to just instantiate other domain objects when you do unit testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing

If you test class Car, and want to create a method on it that returns the number of seats. Is it enough to just write `car.addSeat(new Seat())` multiple times without actually setting some data on the seat if it isn't needed? The method would look something like:

```
public int numberOfSeats() {
    return seats.size();
}
```

given that seats is a list of seats. Or would you fill data on the seat even though it isn't needed? Should you always just try to keep the effort on writing tests at a minimum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using mocking. With mocking you can control how the object that's not being tested behaves using expectations.

e.g.
when(seat.getSomeProperty()).thenReturn("some value")

But if you don't need the value you can just leave the expectation out of your code. This way the code could be updated without rewriting the test and maintaing your test is much simpler.

Checkout Mockito
https://code.google.com/p/mockito/

Comment: 1) So you use mocking for domain classes too? 2) Is mocking like that better than creating empty objects like I did?

Comment: Yes, it's better because you have full control over the object. Here is a scenario from real world example. 
I created very thin domain object with two properties. Someone decided that one of the properties should be required and added the property to a constructor. 
In the test I did not care to pass that property so i just created a mock with ObjA a = mock(ObjA.class) and could create any behavior i want.

Comment: Mocking allows you clearly define what's under test and what's just a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I have two approaches in mind.

1. Define exactly what you want to test and you will know exactly what data needs to be filled. In your example, it wouldn't be neccesary to fill the seats.
2. If you want to test more than just numberOfSeats, you can use setUp and tearDown to create a reusable set of data for each of your tests. JUnit runs setUp before EACH test, and tearDown after.